# Protect ajax php script post call

Tags: php, jquery, email, post

The best description of starting position would be this [Sending Emails With PHP & jQuery](http://www.webmastertalkforums.com/php-tutorials/78-sending-emails-php-jquery.html) text.

TL;DR I am calling a php script with jQuery.post(). Php has something like this inside

```
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$message = $_REQUEST['content'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$header = "From: <".$from.">" ."\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

And the question is how can I protect my mail script from abuse by creating a js cycle and calling it a million times? Or just from calling it with post?

Comment: Session, CSRF token, CAPTCHA... Basically everything from normal forms also applies to AJAX forms, and is on server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid automated form submission normally web developers use `CAPTCHA`. You should also use image based `CAPTCHA` to make your form secure.

Comment: The point was to send registration confirmation mail without user having to wait. It would be strange to have a sidescript asking for captcha, wouldn't it?

Comment: what I understand is you have a registration form and after user fill form and submit form you send confirmation email to the user. Am i right? if so, in your registration form put CAPTCHA at the end or use what joomla uses for form validation to avoid multiple submission

Comment: Joomla generate random hash value and put that value in a hidden field of form, and save that value in session at the same time. when user submit form it check that hidden form value with session.
Hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

The defence against multiple calls has to be server side. Your client code can be modified by an attacker, or the attacker can write his own client.

I would look into throttling strategies, and if this is not to much work, into authentication, which can make throttling a lot more effective. The most naive way to throttle would be to keep track of the last time the script got executed and only allow re-execution if this was longer then a certain amount of time in the past. This info needs to be stored persistently, perhaps on disk in a file or in a db.

Comment: Still this does not protect it from passing wrong data. But I can pass information with session and then throttle calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's also not save to trust user input in the $to and $header parameter. An attacker could add hundreds of recipients so he even doesn't need to call the script multiple times.